# solana zk program

Tags: solana-program, zkp, zk-proof

I couldn't find any example of usage, I'm trying the following and getting `Attempt to load a program that does not exist`.

This is trying the official Solana zk-program:

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/bc136423b4a6f4609e2d07a0b863bc452b84a3ea/zk-token-sdk/src/zk_token_proof_program.rs#L11C30-L11C73

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/bc136423b4a6f4609e2d07a0b863bc452b84a3ea/zk-token-sdk/src/zk_token_proof_instruction.rs#L440

```
   let url = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com".to_string();
    let connection = RpcClient::new(url);
    let wallet = read_keypair_file("id.json").unwrap();
    let keypair = ElGamalKeypair::new_rand();
    let amount: u64 = 55;
    let ciphertext = keypair.pubkey().encrypt(amount);
    let (commitment, opening) = Pedersen::new(amount);

    let proof_data = CiphertextCommitmentEqualityProofData::new(
        &keypair,
        &ciphertext,
        &commitment,
        &opening,
        amount,
    )
    .unwrap();

    let pubkey_validity_data = PubkeyValidityData::new(&keypair).unwrap();
    pubkey_validity_data.verify_proof().unwrap();

    let latest_blockhash = connection.get_latest_blockhash().unwrap();

    let instruction = verify_ciphertext_commitment_equality(None, &pubkey_validity_data);
    let txn = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
        &[instruction],
        Some(&wallet.pubkey()),
        &[&wallet],
        latest_blockhash,
    );

    match connection.send_and_confirm_transaction(&txn) {
        Ok(sig) => loop {
            if let Ok(confirmed) = connection.confirm_transaction(&sig) {
                if confirmed {
                    println!("Transaction: {} Status: {}", sig, confirmed);
                    break;
                }
            }
        },
        Err(e) => println!("Error:, {}", e),
    }
```

Also, didn't find anywhere to use `proof_data`.
In general, seems like the whole `zk-program` is lacking on documentation.

Comment: Could you please add some more information. Which zk-program are you using?  The one from light protocol? Maybe the program is not deployed to mainnet yet. Try devnet for your url instead maybe: https://api.devnet.solana.com

Comment: This one https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/bc136423b4a6f4609e2d07a0b863bc452b84a3ea/zk-token-sdk/src/zk_token_proof_instruction.rs#L440

Comment: If we check the address on Solana Explorer it's missing https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/bc136423b4a6f4609e2d07a0b863bc452b84a3ea/zk-token-sdk/src/zk_token_proof_program.rs#L11C30-L11C73 , but since the address doesn't seem like a real PubKey I was thinking maybe it's embedded into Solana VM. Seems not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the token extensions status page the zk features will be available spring 2024 since they depend on solana 1.18.

https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/status

Comment: The docs on ZK are horrible https://docs.solana.com/developing/runtime-facilities/zk-token-proof nothing mentioning which release, examples etc.. But I assume you're correct since it's obviously missing.

Comment: It'll come even earlier, with 1.17! The extra features in 1.18 are for confidential transfers with fees.